# How to remove <object> white border

Tags: html, object

I have an `<object>` in my page code and my background color is not white. The object is created with a white border, which I don't want.

Any ideas on how to make it `border: 0px;` or `border-color: #whatever;`? Neither of those work. Can someone help me figure this out. Thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem? Maybe make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or a [Codepen](http://www.codepen.io) out of it, or show us your page? What does your CSS look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably seeing an outline rule. This `CSS` should remove it:

```
object {
  border: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

You should probably get rid of the `!important` tags once you make sure that works.

When debugging something in the browser, you should be able to see what styles are set within the browser console. In Chrome, for example, you can right click on an element and it will show you exactly what styles are being applied to any given DOM element.

Comment: ahhhh.... that seems to work but i realized there was a border around the content. I am a failure :P